# properly reset draggable jquery instance

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

check it out... http://thetally.efinancialnews.com/tallyassets/suebanks/suebanks.html

OK so I have 20 or so draggable elements on the right. You can drag one of these onto the 'judge' to the left and all or most of the people below dissapear. You can then press reset.

Everything works great up to here, its only when you try this process again that you realise something didn't properly reset. If you do the first part of the process there is a massive delay and the people fade. I can't see anything in my script asking it to wait so long for anything. I'm confused, I thought my code would correctly reset everything, am I missing something?

Heres the jQuery...

```
$( init );

function init() {

    $("#reset").click(function(){


revertDraggable($(".draggable"));

}); 

$('.draggable').draggable( {
containment: '#maincontain',
stack: '.bankbox div',
cursor: 'move',
revert: 'invalid'
} );
$('.judge').droppable( {
drop: handleDropEvent
} );
}

function handleDropEvent(event, ui) {
 if (!ui.draggable.data("originalPosition")) {
        ui.draggable.data("originalPosition",
            ui.draggable.data("draggable").originalPosition);
    }
var draggable = ui.draggable;
ui.draggable.addClass( "dropped" );
$(".bank").addClass( "undraggable" );
$(".draggable").draggable({
cancel: ".undraggable"
});
ui.draggable.position({
    of: $(this),
    my: 'center bottom',
    at: 'center bottom'
});



var lawyers = $('.lawyers .lawyer');
lawyers.not('.'+draggable.attr('id')).fadeTo( "slow" , 0.1);
lawyers.filter('.'+draggable.attr('id')).fadeTo( "slow" , 1);
}

function revertDraggable($selector) {
$selector.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        position = $this.data("originalPosition");

    if (position) {
        $this.animate({
            left: position.left,
            top: position.top
        }, 500, function() {
            $this.data("originalPosition", null);
        });
    }

    $( ".lawyer" ).fadeTo( "slow" , 1);

    $(".bank").removeClass( "undraggable" );

});

}
```

I'm fairly new to jQuery so there is probably something glaringly obvious!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 function revertDraggable($selector) {
    $selector.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            position = $this.data("originalPosition");
        if (position) {
            $this.animate({
                left: position.left,
                top: position.top
            }, 500, function() {
                $this.data("originalPosition", null);
                $( ".lawyer" ).fadeTo( "slow" , 1); // <--Move this line to here
            });
        }
        $(".bank").removeClass( "undraggable" );
    });
 }
```

Resetting the faded `.lawyer` elements is done after animation delay. (500ms in this case)